# highlight a text in textview

Tags: iphone

How can we highlight a text in textview like the imgage shown below,the user tap the select verse it hilight the verse in yellow color and a popup window apper for that verse for doing action.How to do this?
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: i believe your example uses the CoreText framework for rendering NSAttributedString objects

Comment: How can i use the core textframe work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only doable using CoreText, because it needs formatting attributes and `NSAttributedString` to display text with multiple font style and colors.

You may be interested in my [`OHAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/) class that is a subclass of `UILabel` to render `NSAttributedString` (obviously it uses CoreText for this).

As setting the background color of a range of text is not directly possible/supported (no corresponding attribute in `NSAttributedString`), you may need to draw the yellow rectangles (before drawing the text) yourself, but I've done this in my class too to manage highlighted links (see `drawActiveLinkHighlightForRect:` method) so you may do a similar thing in your case.

Comment: you need to calculate the text size based on glyph info or convenience methods of the framesetter. OR you can create a detailed data structure that contains, (attributed) text and rects for selection, touch detection etc.

Comment: Yes do what Martin said, and look at my `drawActiveLinkHighlightForRect:` in my source that does just that (drawing the background rect of a given text range). That may seem a little complex but it manages cases when the text to highlight crosses multiple lines (like in your screenshot)

Comment: Did you configure the OHAttributedLabel right? Check my sample project in the github repo, I put a lot of examples in there. Try to affect your verses in this sample project to check that it works. Check also that your `OHAttributedLabel* lable1` is high enough (frame big enough to display the attributedString) or use `sizeToFit` to size it accordingly. _(Note that if you have trouble you can search SO there are multiple Q&As about my `OHAttributedLabel` here)_

Comment: app crashes when i put this.i take label1 for displaying the verses.

Comment: Can't help without seeing any code nor the exception details of the crash or any other detail (I've lost my crystal ball, sorry)

Comment: I don't really understand : (1) what you are talking about with this alertview (still didn't find my crystal ball), (2) in what is this related to OHAttributedLabel (3) where is your code you tried (4) what is the error or exception you have. I'm not a medium, and your issue seems not related to the original question of highlighting some text, so please do open a new question and post some code to explain what you tried, what are the errors you gets, etc... (or read the SO FAQ)

Comment: @AliSoftware sir i got everything right,my verse highlighted when i tap the verse.but fist question:how can i remove the undeline and dottet line of the link in label3 of your example code?second question:when the link in lable3 is taped there comes a alertview with message,i formated this alertview with buttons in it,but i cant give actions for he button in the alertview,becz deligate:self it shows self undeclared.i hope u undestand my question